# Why Heroku only returns code 500 for all errors?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I've built an API with Spring boot and deployed it on heroku and for some reason its only error codes that it returns is 500 and 404 from what I've tested, 500 being the problematic one because the server returns it instead of the codes I've defined in the global exception handler. Here the Global exception handler class

```
package com.example.rosaapi.utils.exceptions;


import com.example.rosaapi.controllers.responses.ErrorResponse;
import io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidCityException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInvalidCityException(InvalidCityException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidEventException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInvalidEventException(InvalidEventException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoResourceFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleNoResourceFoundException(NoResourceFoundException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidDateTimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleHandleIllegalDateTimeFormatException(InvalidDateTimeException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CalendarServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleCalendarServiceErrorException(CalendarServiceException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CalendarCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleCalendarCredentialsException(CalendarCredentialsException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(errorResponse);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(ExistentEventException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleExistentEventException(ExistentEventException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RequestNotPermitted.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleExistentEventException(RequestNotPermitted ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS).body(errorResponse);
    }
}
```

One of the examples is when the code supposed to be the return is a 409, which was how I found out about this problem. When the user posts a new Google Calendar Event and a event is already registered at the time it should return a 409, which was not the case, the server returned 500, when I tried to send a bad request for the same operation, it still returned 500. When there was no conflict or bad request and the operation was done sucessfully it returns code 200 normally.